# Best Practices for a Dot Net Core Scheduled Job for point-to-point integrations in a closed On Premise environment

Tags: rest, .net-core, architecture, scheduled-tasks

Working with a on premise customer in a closed on premise environment.

Need to set up some scheduled import/export jobs which involves the exchange of data between their systems. Most follow this process: extract data from one system, call an endpoint of another system to add/update data.

Normally I would make these as webservices and use Azure Scheduler/batch to call them or a middleware solution such as Kafka however these options are not available for this customer.

What is the best practice these days to do scheduling without the tools above? Windows scheduler?

Also are there any tools/programming techniques to deal with failure/retry scenarios

Thanks in advance!